# How to show error message with cancel icon inside textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

I am designing a login screen and its design is given above.

I am using `flutter_bloc` library to set the disable state of `ElevatedButton`.

Now i want to display error message with cross icon in for password and email validation as show in the image.
I have made a custom file named `custom_input` to display the `TextField`.
How can i achieve the flow as shown in image.
Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter Description (Html or Normal Text)',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Description',
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          right: 0, left: 10, top: 15, bottom: 5),
                      suffixIcon: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 15,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                          child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.close, size: 15),
                              onPressed: () {
                                descriptionCtrl.clear();
                              }),
                        ),
                      )),
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
                  minLines: 5,
                  maxLines: null,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  controller: descriptionCtrl,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) return 'Value is empty';
                    return null;
                  },
                  onChanged: (String value) {
                    setState(() {
                      description = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
```